# go over and search in numpy array faster

Tags: python

my array looks like in the picture:

[image: my array]

I would like to know how to return an array(newarr) with the following logic(here is a pseudo code):I need it to be implement as faster as possible!
please help be to write it in the correct and faster way in python.(maybe using numpy,i understand that numpy is fast)

```
i=0
for x in arraynumpy
  i=i+1
  for y in arraynumpy[0:i-1]
     if x[0]==y[1] and x[1]==y[0] and x[2]==y[2]
        newarr.append(x)
        continue;  # break the loop for y,if found
```

the array that will be returned  for the input like in the picture,will be:
[[20,10,'1'],[30,10,'1']]

thank you

Comment: in what "i" is used? "index" is not defined; is "i" supposed to be the same as "index"??

Comment: yes sorry i=index it is a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo-code is in quadratic time. Here is a solution which is in linear time (much better if you have big inputs). It does not use numpy arrays, as I don't think that would help getting better performance.

```py
def find_stuff(l):
    result = []
    index = set()
    for x1, x2, x3 in l:
        if (x2, x1, x3) in index:
            result.append((x1, x2, x3))
        index.add((x1, x2, x3))
    return result
```

And, on your example:

```
>>> a = [(10, 20, 1), (10, 30, 1), (10, 50, 1), (10, 108, 1), (10, 200010, 1), (20, 10, 1), (20, 108, 1), (20, 710, 1), (20, 710, 1), (20, 200020, 1), (30, 10, 1)]
>>> find_stuff(a)
[(20, 10, 1), (30, 10, 1)]
>>>
```

Note that if you really need better performance, maybe you should consider using an other language, as Python is quite slow.

Comment: thank you! It seems to do the work! But maybe with numpy using the function numpy.where(condition, [x, y, ]/) it will be faster? it is with huge data and i need it to be faster and i can use only python.do you know how to do that with numpy builded in functions ,so that i can compare performance?thank you